# How to solve $12-\sin(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$12-\sin(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$$

What's the correct answer on the $[0,2\pi]$?

I started with  $12-\sin(\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$ and then i cant get anything sensible as i end up with $12=\sin(\theta)+2\sin^2(\theta)$

Comment: what about using quadratic formula?

Comment: The sum of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos 2\theta$ cannot be anywhere near $12$.  It is useful to *look* before calculating.

Comment: Le left hand side should be 11 instead of 12, (since 12-1=11). Also, the sign in the RHS should - instead of +

Comment: To expand on the answers, this can be solved in a systematic way with the fourier transform together with linearity and $multiplication \rightarrow convolution$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $-1\le \sin \theta \le 1\implies 11\le 12-\sin \theta \le 13$

Also $-1\le\cos \theta \le 1\implies -1\le \cos 2\theta \le 1$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: @John thanks for editing my simple mistake :)

Comment: spasibo tovarish!!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** So far so good: $$2\sin^2\theta + \sin\theta - 12= 0 \implies \sin \theta = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot 2 \cdot(-12)}}{2\cdot 2}.$$

Find two possible values for $\sin \theta$. Then find the possible values for $\theta$ (will there be any?).

Comment: muchos gracias!!!!

Answer (score 2):

you are almost there. $$2\sin^2 \theta + \sin \theta - 12=0 $$ so $$\sin \theta = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{49}}{4} = -2, \frac32$$ neither of them leads to a solution for $\theta.$

we should have seen this from the equation itself. reason is $$1 \ge |\cos 2\theta| = |12 - \sin \theta | \ge 11$$ a contradiction.

Comment: Hi Abel, I think the Delta is not $49$ but $97$, indeed $\sin\theta=-2$ is not a root :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
12\sin \theta  &=&\cos (2\theta ) \\
&=&1-2\sin ^{2}\theta 
\end{eqnarray*}
then
\begin{equation*}
2\sin ^{2}\theta +12\sin \theta -1=0.
\end{equation*}
Let $X=\sin \theta ,$ then
\begin{equation*}
2X^{2}+12X-1=0
\end{equation*}
This quadratic equation have two roots: $X_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{38}-3$ and $%
X_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{38}-3.$ Note that $X_{2}<-3$ then $X_{2}\notin \left[
-1,1\right] ,$ then it cannot provide a $\theta -solution$ to the original
equation. Next, $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{38}-3\simeq 0.082\,2\in \left[ -1,1\right] 
$ then one has
\begin{equation*}
\sin \theta =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{38}-3
\end{equation*}
and then
\begin{equation*}
\theta =\arcsin \left( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{38}-3\right) \simeq 0.0823\ rad
\end{equation*}
Remark. It is known that when $\theta $ (in rad) is so small then $\sin \theta
\simeq \theta .$ Since our $\sin \theta =X_{1}\simeq 0.082\,2$ is so small
then it is not surprising to find $\theta \simeq \sin \theta .$

Comment: This this the solution to the first equation which was on the title of your post. It seems that it is not the same now. Never mind, the technique of solving remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

$12-\sin(\theta)$ oscillates between 11 and 13.

$\cos(2\theta)$oscillates between 1 and -1.

$ 11> 1. $

The two graphs have no cutting point, so no real roots solution at all, but complex roots are:

$ \sin^{-1}(-2), \sin^{-1}{} \frac32. $

Answer (score 0):

From

> $$12-\sin(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$$

you get
$$12-\sin(\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta),$$
this is
$$12-\sin(\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta).$$
Hence
$$2\sin^2(\theta)-\sin(\theta)+11=0$$
and
$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\cdot2\cdot11}}{4}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-87}}{4}.$$
So, no real solution for $\sin(\theta)$ means no real solution for $\theta$ and, in particular, no solution $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Indeed, $12-\sin(\theta)\in[11,13]$ while $\cos(2\theta)\in[-1,1]$, for all $\theta\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

$$12-\sin(x)=\cos(2x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$12-\cos(2x)-\sin(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$11-\sin(x)+2\sin^2(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\frac{11}{2}-\frac{\sin(x)}{2}+\sin^2(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\sin^2(x)-\frac{\sin(x)}{2}=-\frac{11}{2}\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\frac{1}{16}-\frac{\sin(x)}{2}+\sin^2(x)=-\frac{87}{16}\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\left(\sin(x)-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2=-\frac{87}{16}\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\sin(x)-\frac{1}{4}=\pm \frac{i\sqrt{87}}{4}\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\sin(x)=\pm \frac{i\sqrt{87}}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\Longleftrightarrow $$

So now the solutions:
$$x_1=2\left(\pi n+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{22}-\frac{i\sqrt{87}}{22}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\frac{570}{121}-\frac{2i\sqrt{87}}{121}}
\right)\right)$$

$$x_2=2\left(\pi n+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{22}+\frac{i\sqrt{87}}{22}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\frac{570}{121}-\frac{2i\sqrt{87}}{121}}
\right)\right)$$

With $n$ is the element of Z -> the set of integers